# Why is CKEditor refusing my custom tag?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, bolt-cms

With a custom CKEditor plugin I am trying to insert a custom HTML tag, but the tag gets removed as soon as it is inserted into the editor. My plugin.js file:

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'tweet', {
    icons: 'tweet',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'insertTweet', {
            allowedContent: 'tweet[:id]',
            requiredContent: 'tweet',
            exec: function( editor ) {
                console.log('inserting');  
                editor.insertHtml( '<tweet :id="\'123\'" />' );  // also tried <tweet />
                // editor.insertHtml( '[tweet :id="\'123\'" /]' ); // this works
            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton( 'tweet', {
            label: 'Insert tweet',
            command: 'insertTweet',
            toolbar: 'insert,0'
        });
    }
});
```

The way I am adding the plugin for Bolt CMS backend:

```js
function run() {
    var extrasAdded = false;

    if (typeof(CKEDITOR) == 'undefined') return;

    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('tweet', '/assets/plugins/tweet/plugin.js', '');

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event, instance) {

        if (extrasAdded === true) return;

        var config = event.editor.config;

        config.toolbar.push(
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'tweet' ] }
        );
        config.extraPlugins += (config.extraPlugins ? ',' : '') + 'tweet';
        config.extraAllowedContent = 'tweet';  // also tried 'tweet[:id]'

        CKEDITOR.instances['body'].destroy();
        CKEDITOR.replace('body', config);

        extrasAdded = true;
    });
}

if (document.readyState!='loading') run();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

Can someone smart see why my tag is rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that we don't need the `allowedContent` or `requiredContent` properties in the plugin.js script. What did the trick was to tweak the editor's [HTML DTD rules](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dtd.html). In my case I got a reference to the editor in the `instanceReady` callback and tweeked it like this:

```
// name = 'tweet'
editor.filter.allow(name + "[!*]", name, true);

CKEDITOR.dtd[name] = CKEDITOR.dtd;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty[name] = 1; // allow self-closing tag
CKEDITOR.dtd.$blockLimit[name] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$nonEditable[name] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$object[name] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline[name] = 1; // $block won't work!
```

You can also see a full [gist of it](https://gist.github.com/JannieT/34119c01d81250f3f050dadf918c49e1).